# minimum leash ,known distances

Tags: algorithm

Let us assume that we have 2 curves , curve P and curve Q . Curve P consists of points p1 ,p2 ...pn and curve  Q consists of points q1,q2...qm  .  A man starts from p1 and ends at pn ,after having visited all points p1,p2,..pn . A dog starts from q1 and ends at qm ,after having visited all q1,q2...qm .

Additional restriction : Points must be visited in a row .To give an example , if the man is at p3 , he can wait at p3 until the dog makes a move , he can move to p4 , but he can never go back to p2 . The same applies for the dog.

We define the distance of 2 points as d(pi,qj) . We assume that d(pi,qj) is calculated at O(1). All distances d(pi,qj) are known.

Our task is to find the minimum possible max distance (minimum leash) d that occures between the man and the dog ,while they move towards pn and qm.

To give an example , if d(p1,q1) =1  , d(p1,q2)=2 , d(p1,q3)=3  ,d(q2,p1)=2.5 ,d(p2,q2)=2.2  and d(p2,q3)=1.8  ,then the minimum max distance is 2 .

step 1: man and dog are at p1 and q1 . Current maximum distance is 1.

step 2: man remains at p1 ,dog moves to q2. Current maximum distance is 2.

step 3:both man and dog move simultaneuosly to p2 and q3 respectively.Maximum distance remains 2.

Which is the most suitable algorithm for this task?It looks like a frechet distance problem...

Comment: "Our task is to find the minimum possible max distance (minimum leash) d that occures between the man and the dog ,while they move towards pn and qm." Unclear: does it mean "makes any bi-walk possible"  or "makes at least one bi-walk possible"?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest dynamic programming. There are at most three possible previous positions for each step. Let `f(i,j)` be the maximum minimal leash distance from `(p1,q1)` to `(pi,pj)`.

Then:

```
f(i,j) = max( d(pi,qj), min(f(i-1,j), f(i,j-1), f(i-1,j-1)) )
```

You could think about building a matrix to hold a bottom-up calculation (actually a triangle emanating from the top left), or another alternative may be memoizing a recursive function. The matrix can be constructed in `O(m*n)` time, and space is only actually needed for two rows. To take your example, we have:

```
d(p1,q1) =1 , d(p1,q2)=2 , d(p1,q3)=3 ,d(q2,p1)=2.5 ,d(p2,q2)=2.2 and d(p2,q3)=1.8

f(2,3) = max(1.8, min(f(1,3),f(2,2),f(1,2)))
```

Clearly `f(1,2)` would be the lowest in the min evaluation, leading to 2 as the solution.

The order for a `dp` construction would look something like this since `f(i-1,j-1)` is a parent of `f(i-1,j)` and `f(i,j-1)` but all three are needed for `f(i,j)`:

```
            1,1
         2,1   1,2
      3,1   2,2   1,3
   4,1   3,2   2,3   1,4
5,1   4,2   3,3   2,4   1,5
```

Apparently there is some published work on computing a more efficient solution. For example: [Agarwal et al. *Computing the discrete Fréchet distance in subquadratic time*](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/papers/frechet.pdf)

And here's an article presenting a formal treatment of the dp algorithm above: [Eiter & Mannila. *Computing Discrete Frechet Distance*](http://www.kr.tuwien.ac.at/staff/eiter/et-archive/cdtr9464.pdf)

Comment: Assume the following sequence of steps - the owner (p positions) stays in p1 all the time, the dog (q pos) goes ahead 3 times - reaching p3 after two steps. With a leash of 2, I'd be forced to call the animal protection agency of the place, you will choke the poor dog.

Comment: Tentatively +1 . . . but so far you haven't actually answered the *algorithm* question, you've just given a multiply-recursive formula. You need to say something about "dynamic programming" or "memoization" or similar.

Comment: @ruakh thank you for your comment (and tentative vote). I added the words "dynamic programming." Is that along the lines you had in mind?

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Yes, perfect. :-)

Comment: The problem goes quite nasty as n and m grow. Under exponential, but over polynomial complexity - somewhere in the factorial range. Except for small n,m, exhaustive explorations are not feasible.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi the article I mention at the end of my answer might interest you.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I took the liberty of rolling back your edit that included notes about the articles - I would prefer to let people read and make their own interpretation and learning from the articles. (Also O(m*n) space for the second article seems incorrect - we only need two rows in memory since the algorithm refers back just to the previous row each time. I commented about complexity in the answer.)

Comment: "I took the liberty of rolling back your edit that included notes about the articles" Your privilege, I won't object. My apologies for wasting your time, then. "we only need two rows in memory since the algorithm refers back just to the previous row each time." I guess it is possible, even if the numbering scheme of the last two rows is a bit more complex - it's all fine and dandy for n==m, but when it comes to n<m or n>m your triangle gets cut/truncated on the side of the lesser dimension - the numbering scheme doesn't look straight-forward to me.

Comment: @גלעדברקן "Also O(m*n) space for the second article seems incorrect" On my defence, the cited article does use a `n x m` matrix (see page 6).